# Finding max in Python dict with nested tuple keys

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, tuples, max

Say I have this Python dict:

```
dict = {
((0,0), 'A'): 0.0, 
((0,0), 'B'): 0.7,
...
((2,4), 'C'): 0.2,
...}
```

I want to find the maximum value for a given nested tuple like (0,0).
Something like:

```
max(dict((0,0), *).
```

In this case it should return 0.7, how to do this?

Comment: Yes the keys are tuples, with one value of the tuple being another tuple.

Comment: I changed the syntax, hope it's correct now. The dict's keys consist of one pair of integer values and a string. I want to find the maximum over all strings.

Comment: Side note: do not name variables after classes, e.g. use `d` or `dict_` instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you you need.

```
d = {((0,0), 'A'): 0.0, ((0,0), 'B'): 0.7, ((2,4), 'C'): 0.2,}
dValue = dict((k, v) for k,v in d.items() if k[0] == (0,0))
print( max(dValue.values()) )
```

**Output:**

```
0.7
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.defaultdict` followed by a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {((0,0), 'A'): 0.0, 
     ((0,0), 'B'): 0.7,
     ((2,4), 'C'): 0.2}

from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)

for (k1, k2), v in d.items():
    res[k1].append(v)

max_vals = {k: max(v) for k, v in res.items()}

print(max_vals)

{(0, 0): 0.7, (2, 4): 0.2}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a very simple example of your question. Surely there is a more efficient way to do it.

```
dict = { ((0, 0), "A"): 0.0,
         ((0, 0), "B"): 0.7, 
         ((0, 0), "C"): 0.9, 
         ((0, 1), "A"): 0.0,
         ((0, 1), "B"): 0.7, 
         ((0, 1), "C"): 0.8}
mymax={}
for key1,key2 in dict:
    if key1 in mymax:
        mymax[key1] = max(mymax[key1],dict[(key1,key2)])
    else:
         mymax[key1] = dict[(key1,key2)]
```

`mymax= {(0, 0): 0.9, (0, 1): 0.8}` has the maximum of every kind.